# android disk cache vs memory cache

Tags: android, caching, memory, disk

I didn't fully understand when should I use memory cache (LruCache) and when to pick disk caching. or should I use them both together?
I looked [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#disk-cache)

Comment: Memory Caching is Automatic, depends on classes that you uses. Some of the Created Layout is stored and String Values as well for Translation purposes or Variable String references. So What are you talking about. Picking what to use?

Comment: Use both. If you use Lru only you will slow down the speed of the device. If you use disk only you will strain the device's storage

Answer (score 6):

**Memory cache :-**

- Faster to access this cache
- This cache take up your application memory so avoid it for storing huge data
- Memory cache gets destroyed once app goes background and gets killed by system to save up resources

**Disk Cache :-**

- Slower than memory cache
- Use it for large cache data
- Data is present even after app goes background

Answer (score 2):

> LruCache

Simply put, `LruCahce` is kinda `HashMap`. It will store your key-value pair during runtime until

1. The application gets killed while on background
2. User exits the application by clicking the back button
3. User rotates the device

Look at the code snippet below. Once one of the action mentioned above happens both `lruCahce` and `randomString` will be removed from the in-memory cache

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LruCache<String, Bitmap> lruCache = new LruCache<>(1 * 1024 * 1024); // That means 1Mb memory will be allocated to this LruCahce object
    String ranDomString;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);

        lruCache.put("first_bitmap_url", firstBitmap);
        lruCache.put("second_bitmap_url", secondBitmap);

        ranDomString = "Random string";
    }
}
```

> DiskLruCahce

On the contrary, `DiskLruCache` will survive all above-mentioned actions (being killed/ exit by back button/ screen rotation) and the next time Activity starts you can read those data from disk. In this case, we can get bitmaps with given keys on the next startup of our application. Below example is a snippet from Android source code:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DiskLruCache disklruCache = new DiskLruCache.open(this.getCacheDir(), 1 * 1024 * 1024); // That means 1Mb memory will be allocated to this DiskLruCahce object

    String ranDomString;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);

        disklruCache.put("first_bitmap_url", firstBitmap);
        disklruCache.put("second_bitmap_url", secondBitmap);

    }
}
```